# Auto injecting logger with guice

Tags: java, guice

With reference to [Guice's custom injections](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomInjections) article, its TypeListener performs a check for InjectLogger.class annotation - which can be optional. Removing that check will inject to all Logger.class types.

```
class Log4JTypeListener implements TypeListener {
    public <T> void hear(TypeLiteral<T> typeLiteral, TypeEncounter<T> typeEncounter) {
      for (Field field : typeLiteral.getRawType().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (field.getType() == Logger.class
            && field.isAnnotationPresent(InjectLogger.class)) {
          typeEncounter.register(new Log4JMembersInjector<T>(field));
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm tempted to remove "**&& field.isAnnotationPresent(InjectLogger.class)**" from the listener.

If we're using Guice to inject all instances of our Logger, is there any reason not to do it automatically (without need to annotate)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any programmatic correctness reasons why you wouldn't want to annotate.

I do think you wouldn't want to inject automatically for the sake of code clarity. Dependency Injection can have a bit of a 'magic' feel to it, annotations help clarify the magic and assist developers in understanding what is happening. Essentially, like a type for a variable, a DI annotation is as much for the developer as for the compiler/interpreter.

All that being said, I think if you weren't going to annotate for your logging classes that isn't a huge deal. Most developers don't think a ton about loggers, they just use them (at least that's been my experience). So in this case it would probably be relatively harmless.